# How to make grid column fit the rest of the space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid wrapper with three columns, where the first column is the biggest and it takes 2fr of width, and the second and the third columns are the same size, and they are taking both 1fr of width. What I want is to create a grid template with a dynamic number of columns, for example, if I remove one of the columns, the rest of the columns should take the remaining size equally.
Here is the fiddle of what I've tried so far

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.third {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="second">
  2
  </div>
 <!-- <div class="third">
  3
  </div> -->
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84pjdyfo/1/)

I've tried with `grid-template-columns: 2fr auto auto`, but that is not working well. The expected result is like this
[image: expected]

but the actual result is like this

[image: actual]

Any idea how can I solve this? All examples will be appreciated!

Comment: Generally that's not possible in CSS-Grid. In fact that's what flexbox is for,

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D Alright, thanks, I will edit my question.

Comment: @Paulie_D I will be happy with the flexbox example too!

Comment: Well there are plenty of questions on "remaining width".

Comment: Indeed as Paulie said, grid is more for when you do know the width/height ahead of time, generally speaking. Flexbox is more flexible, and so is designed to work well there. You can combine the two to work in concert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rely on implicit columns:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-columns: 50%; /* one explicit column */
  grid-auto-columns:1fr; /* implicit column created when needed */
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.first:last-child {
   grid-column:span 2; /* full width if alone */
}

.second {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.third {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
  1
  </div>
  <!--<div class="second">
  2
  </div>-->
 <!-- <div class="third">
  3
  </div> -->
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="second">
  2
  </div>
 <!-- <div class="third">
  3
  </div> -->
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="second">
  2
  </div>
 <div class="third">
  3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is really awesome, thanks. I know i didn't mention that on the question, but what if I remove 2 boxes? Then the remaining box will take only 50% of wrapper instead of 100%. How can I solve that?

Comment: Sorry if I'm bothering you, but what if any other div is alone? I've tried something like this `.wrapper > div:last-child {
   grid-column:span 2; /* full width if alone */
}` but that is not good :(

Comment: @Milos if you want it to work with any div use `div:only-child {}` or `div:first-child:last-child {}`

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you very much sir!